How to find a minimum for the values of a parameter in a function?
I have several running times which I would like to balance. For example, say I have an algorithm which has a part that runs in $n^{2+a}$ time and another part which runs in $n^{3-a}$ time. To balance these times, I'd choose $a=\frac{1}{2}$, hence making the runtime $n^{\frac{5}{2}}$.
Generally, I am trying to use Maple to balance such runtime terms. I tried to use Minimize on the function $n^{2+a}+n^{3-a}$, but could not find how to describe in the Minimize command that $n$ is a variable I am not interested in minimizing (i.e., let $n$ remain a variable), while the value I want to minimize is actually the parameter $a$. Attempting to Minimize so far resulted either in an error, or in setting a value to both $a$ and $n$ (where I would like only $a$ to be given a value, and let $n$ remain a variable).
Another idea I had was to remove $n$. That is, consider the function $\max\left\{2+a,3-a\right\}$. Invoking Minimize on this function should yield $a=\frac{1}{2}$ and bring my quest to an end. Yet, I got an error:

NLPSolver: No Improved Point could be found

Which likely means Maple can't Minimize a function with a $\min$ or $\max$ expression?
Anyway, the $\max$ was just an attempt to overcome the initial problem, where I could not tell Maple to let $n$ remain a variable, and only find a value to $a$.

I'm not familiar with Maple, but I have two ideas

Can you declare $n$ as an unknown parameter?
Try optimizing the following which is equivalent to your reduced problem
\begin{align}
\min_{a} ;& x \
\text{s.t.} ;& x \geq 2 + a \
& x \geq 3 - a
\end{align}


Your description is confusing. Do you mean that you want to find the $a$ that minimizes $n^{2+a} + n^{3-a}$? (Note that it is the expression that is being "minimized", not $a$. The desired $a$ is the "arg min" or "minimizing argument" for the expression.) The derivative of $n^{2+a} + n^{3-a}$ with respect to $a$ is $(n^{2+a} - n^{3-a})\ln n$ which will be $0$ when $n^{2+a} = n^{3-a}$, which is when $2+a = 3-a$, regardless of the value of $n$. So you could just teill it to minimize $e^{2+a} + e^{3-a}$ or $2^{2+a} + 2^{3-a}$ instead.

However, I doubt you are accomplishing what you think you are accomplishing here. When we say an algorithm runs in $n^\alpha$ time, It means that there is some constant $M$ such that the runtime is $\le Mn^\alpha$ for all $n$. So the expression you need to be minimizing is actually $Mn^{2+a} + Nn^{3 - a}$, where $M, N$ are the constant multipliers for the two parts, which are unlikely to be the same, and may even vary with however you are adjusting the algorithms to fit $a$. The minimum for this is $a = \frac12(1+\log_n \left(\frac NM\right))$, a different value, that changes with $n$.
